# React memo() clearing hook state - old data reappears

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use React memo() for the first time in order to prevent unnecessary re-rendering of the *TextInputs* for the *notes*. These re-renders are successfully prevented and the page performance is slightly improved (there can be hundreds of notes in a real example).

However, afterpressing the *Reset-button*, strange things happens. Changing a note that has not previously been edited causes old notes to reappear in the other *TextInputs*.

My question is:
Why does the old notes reappear in this way, and how can I work around it while still keeping the optimized rendering?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export const ReRendering = () => {

    const defaultNotes = [
        {id: '0155', note: ''},
        {id: '0197', note: ''},
        {id: '0045', note: ''},
        {id: '0244', note: ''},
        {id: '0162', note: ''},
    ];

    const [notes, setNotes] = useState(defaultNotes);


    function updateNote(e) {

        let newNotes = [];

        notes.map(r => {
            if(e.target.name === r.id) {
                r.note = e.target.value;
            }
            newNotes.push(Object.assign(r));
        });

        setNotes(newNotes);

    }


    return (

        <div className={'mt-5'}>

            <h3>Notes</h3>

            <table className={'table table-sm'}>
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Note</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
            {notes.map(note => {
                return (
                    <tr key={note.id}>
                        <td>
                            <input type={'text'}
                                   disabled
                                   className={'form-control border-0'}
                                   value={note.id}
                            />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <MemoTextInput
                                value={note.note}
                                name={note.id}
                                handleChange={updateNote}
                            />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                )

            })}
            </tbody>
            </table>

            <button onClick={() => setNotes(defaultNotes)}>Revert</button>

        </div>
    )
};

const TextInput = ({value, handleChange, name}) => {

    return (
        <input
            type={'text'}
            className={'form-control'}
            value={value}
            onChange={handleChange}
            name={name}
        />
    )

};

function areEqual(prevProps, nextProps) {
    return prevProps.value === nextProps.value;
}

const MemoTextInput = React.memo(TextInput, areEqual);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem had to do with the updateNote() function. The TextInputs that didn't re-render had an old version of *updateNote()* on it and therefor also an old version of *notes*.

With this revised version of updateNotes() it works properly.

```
function updateNote({target}){

        setNotes(oldNotes => {
            const newNotes = [...oldNotes];
            newNotes.filter(n => n.id === target.name)[0] = {...oldNotes.filter(n => n.id === target.name)[0]};
            newNotes.filter(n => n.id === target.name)[0].note = target.value;
            return newNotes;
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When assigning `r.note = e.target.value;` you are changing the original state (the default note), which can have bad effects to everything else.

```
const newNotes = notes.map(r => {
   if (e.target.name === r.id) {
      return { ...r, note: e.target.value };
   } else {
      // no need to copy object here, it would only make your performance worse
      return r;
   }
});
```